# Allert box using `meteor Js`?

Tags: meteor

I need help i am new to `meteor Js`. I am trying to implement by click on button open alert box by using **meteor Js** ,but it does not work.Please help me here is my code below see and suggest me.Here give the some clarification by click on Episode info as mentioned in template open a dialogbox.

template:

```
    <template name="newclientinfoform">
    <div><a class="clientinfodetails" href="">Episode Info</a></div>
    </template>
```

ClientJs:

```
    Template.newclientinfoform.events({ 
             'click .clientinfodetails' : function CustomAlert(e,t)
             {
                  if (typeof console !== 'undefined')      
             console.log("You pressed the ClientDetails Row");
             e.preventDefault();    
                //alert("Episode Info");
            this.render = function(dialog){
            var winW = window.innerWidth;
               var winH = window.innerHeight;
            var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
               var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
            dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
               dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
            dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
               dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
               dialogbox.style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Alert Box Header";
               document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = dialog;
            document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.ok()" class="btn">OK</button>';
            }
            this.ok = function(){
            document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
            }
            }`
        });
```

CSS:

```
#dialogbox{
display: none;
position: fixed;
background: red;
border-radius:7px;
width:550px;
z-index: 10;
}
#dialogbox > div{ background:#FFF; margin:8px; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxhead{ background: #666; font-size:19px; padding:10px; color:#CCC; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxbody{ background:#333; padding:20px; color:#FFF;fon-family:verdana; }
#dialogbox > div > #dialogboxfoot{ background: #666; padding:10px; text-align:right; }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be manipulating DOM directly. Instead, put the content you want to display in an alert within a template, and render that template. Why don't you try using [Crater package](http://code.subhog.com/crater#alert) for that? It has the exact functionality.

Comment: Hubert - nice work, very pleasant website!  I'll be checking out client-call as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reactive way would be to just store the visibility state of your dialog box / alert in a Session variable, then have your template listen to that state and show it when the visibility is true. For example, in the template that would show the dialog:

```
{{#if showDialog}}
  <div id="myDialog"><!-- dialog markup here --></div>
{{/if}}

<button id="showDialog">show dialog</button>
```

And in the template javascript:

```
Template.myTemplate.showDialog = function() {
  return Session.get('showDialog');
};

Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click #showDialog': function() {
    Session.set('showDialog', true);
  }
});
```

Clicking on a close button (or the modal's backdrop) could `Session.set('showDialog',false);`